# How to create multiple slideshows on my front page?

Tags: views

I am new to Drupal and I don't know how can I create multiple slideshows on my front page.

I am developing an image sharing website where users will upload their images. I want that when a user adds a gallery a slideshow is made on the front page. Like if I have four users means I will give four different slideshows on the front page.

Any help?

Comment: What if you have 1000 users, 1000 different slideshows in the front page ??? O_O

Comment: Do you want users to each see their own personalised slidehsow on the front page?

Comment: Yes if i have 1000 users and they and all of them add thier own gallery than i will have thousand slideshows on the fron page

Comment: What version of drupal are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using [Views Slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) as it is a very easy to install and configurable module if you are used to using Views in Drupal.

All you would have to do then is intwine your logic, looping through users and their associated uploaded images and place the block on your front page.

Here is a tutorial for [drupal 8](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/drupal-8-slideshows/) and [drupal 7](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/views-slideshow/) using views slideshow:

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities from here, you can either

1. Use a jquery pluggin for beautiful sliders and add back-end functionality to it (use display suite module). I'd suggest Owl Carousel, Google it, Learn it, Use it. It's very simple.
2. Use the [Colorbox](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox) module. It's not as beautiful as #1, but it's extremely simple, easy to use, clean and to the point. It can automatic create slider of gallery of pictures your users will upload on your site.

Plus: Best thing about these options is that, they are very light-weight and there is almost no performance loss. I use them in half dozens of my site.
However the only negative factor might be: they don't require any coding, however you can use them the way you want.

Update:
If you use bootstrap (which you probably do, I mean who doesn't use BS), then there is nothing easier and simpler than [Bootstrap Carousel](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/).

Comment: About your last phrase: and why would that be a negative factor? Apart from for the Drupal developer who would miss the business opportunity to deliver whatever required coding ...

Comment: What's fun in that if it's no coding. These libraries does the business themselves. We just have to call them :D

Comment: I can understand "you" think of it as "no fun". However, over the years I've learned that it's also "fun" if you meet a customer from long time ago, who tells you "hey, remember that special thing you delivered to us? Guess what: we still use it today, and it keeps working". What such customer often doesn't realize, is that the underlying code (or OS) has been upgraded, and the original (out of the box) solution uses techniques that are still supported. To me those anecdotes are way much more "fun". Just another viewpoint ...

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bad idea. Slideshows add quite an amount of javascript to a page and having a lot of them on the page will mean that your page will be slower to load than you might like.

If you want to do this, what you'll need to do is create an image field (probably on a content type called "Gallery" or something) that allows people to upload multiple images.

After this, install the flexslider module (or some other slideshow module - flexslider is very popular and fairly easy to use). Then on the "Manage Display" page for this content type, set the field formatter to flexslider. You can configure the flexslider settings on the flexslider configuration page under `/admin/config/media/flexslider`

You will then need to use Views to list the nodes that have this image field and place that view on the front page (as a block or by making a views page and setting that to the front page).

Without knowing more about your exact requirements, I can't give you an exact solution, but the above should will get you started.

In short, you need:
- An multivalue image field
- Flexslider module (and library)
- Views

Comment: Sir what you had mentioned is what I have tried but because of doing this I am getting slideshow in the content area as I want that on the first page slideshows of the images are present and when the click on the content their they see individual images.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this module could be useful for you : [Field Slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_slideshow)

It will provide a new Field formatter for an Image field (display) and you will have your slideshow each time someone enters values for that Image field.

Another module that could be useful for users : [Multiupload Imagefield Widget](https://www.drupal.org/project/multiupload_imagefield_widget)

It will provide a new Field Widget for an Image field (form) and you will be able to upload multiple images at once, selecting them directly on your computer. It saves time but watch yout maximum upload size settings.

Finally, you will need Views to create a Users view displaying the Image field. To avoid the 1000 users as it was noticed, I suggest you display only the last 4 or 5 users. This view could thus be displayed on your frontpage, directly (replace the default front) or through Panels if you need to add someting else around this View. CSS to design everything and you're good.

Hope this helps.